# Installing Pfsense in KVM

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, installation, pfsense

I am trying to install PFsense in KVM and it keeps failing for not finding an installable distribution.

What does the following error mean?

```
Fetching volume XML failed: Storage volume not found: no storage vol with matching path
```

Here is the install command I am running:

```
virt-install --debug --name=Firewall --memory=4096 --vcpus=2 \
   --location=/opt/OS_Images/pfSense-CE-2.4.1-RELEASE-amd64.iso \
   --disk=/var/lib/libvirt/images/Firewall.qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio,size=10 \
   --network bridge:virbr0 --os-type=linux --nographics \
   --extra-args='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

Here is the complete --debug from the install attempt:

```
   [root@s119918 OS_Images]# virt-install --debug --name=Firewall --memory=4096 --vcpus=2 --location=/opt/OS_Images/pfSense-CE-2.4.1-RELEASE-amd64.iso --disk=/var/lib/libvirt/images/Firewall.qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio,size=10 --network bridge:virbr0  --os-type=linux  --nographics --extra-args='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (cli:261) Launched with command line: /usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install --debug --name=Firewall --memory=4096 --vcpus=2 --location=/opt/OS_Images/pfSense-CE-2.4.1-RELEASE-amd64.iso --disk=/var/lib/libvirt/images/Firewall.qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio,size=10 --network bridge:virbr0 --os-type=linux --nographics --extra-args=console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (cli:275) Requesting libvirt URI default
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (cli:279) Received libvirt URI qemu:///system
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (virt-install:358) Requesting virt method 'default', hv type 'default'.
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (virt-install:582) Received virt method 'kvm'
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (virt-install:583) Hypervisor name is 'hvm'
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (virt-install:270) Distilled --network options: ['bridge=virbr0']
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (virt-install:316) --graphics compat generated: none
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (virt-install:183) Distilled --disk options: ['/var/lib/libvirt/images/Firewall.qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio,size=10']
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (connection:243) Fetching volume XML failed: Storage volume not found: no storage vol with matching path '/var/lib/libvirt/images/Jira_Confluence.qcow2'
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (connection:243) Fetching volume XML failed: Storage volume not found: no storage vol with matching path '/var/lib/libvirt/images/jira_Confluence.img'
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (connection:243) Fetching volume XML failed: Storage volume not found: no storage vol with matching path '/var/lib/libvirt/images/Jira_Confluence.qcow2.dsk'
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (connection:243) Fetching volume XML failed: Storage volume not found: no storage vol with matching path '/opt/Kvm_Images/Jira_Confluence.qcow2'
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (connection:243) Fetching volume XML failed: Storage volume not found: no storage vol with matching path '/opt/Kvm_Images/jira_Confluence.img'
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (guest:250) Setting Guest.os_variant to 'linux'
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] WARNING (virt-install:544) No operating system detected, VM performance may suffer. Specify an OS with --os-variant for optimal results.
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (virt-install:696) Guest.has_install_phase: True

Starting install...
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:57) Using scratchdir=/var/lib/libvirt/boot
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:302) Preparing mount at /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:312) mount cmd: ['/bin/mount', '-o', 'ro,loop', '/opt/OS_Images/pfSense-CE-2.4.1-RELEASE-amd64.iso', '/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu']
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:477) Finding distro store for location=/opt/OS_Images/pfSense-CE-2.4.1-RELEASE-amd64.iso
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/Fedora) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:1107) Found treearch=amd64 in uri
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/current/images/MANIFEST) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/daily/MANIFEST) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:1107) Found treearch=amd64 in uri
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/current/images/MANIFEST) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/install/netboot/version.info) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/.disk/info) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/SL) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/CentOS) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/VERSION) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/.disk/info) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/Server) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/Client) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/RedHat) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/ppc/ppc64/vmlinuz) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/images/boot.iso) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/boot/boot.iso) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu/install/images/boot.iso) returning False
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:145) hasFile(/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu) returning True
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (urlfetcher:326) Cleaning up mount at /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.QnwwMu
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (cli:314)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 1007, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 1001, in main
    start_install(guest, options)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 727, in start_install
    fail(e, do_exit=False)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/cli.py", line 314, in fail
    logging.debug("".join(traceback.format_stack()))

[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] ERROR (cli:315) Could not find an installable distribution at '/opt/OS_Images/pfSense-CE-2.4.1-RELEASE-amd64.iso'

The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
See virt-install man page for various distro examples.
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (cli:317)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 706, in start_install
    transient=options.transient)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 479, in start_install
    self._prepare_install(meter, dry)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 312, in _prepare_install
    self.installer.prepare(self, meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/installer.py", line 200, in prepare
    self._prepare(guest, meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 220, in _prepare
    self._prepare_kernel_url(guest, fetcher)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 127, in _prepare_kernel_url
    store = self._get_store(guest, fetcher)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 114, in _get_store
    self._cached_store = urlfetcher.getDistroStore(guest, fetcher)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/urlfetcher.py", line 528, in getDistroStore
    (fetcher.location, extramsg)))
ValueError: Could not find an installable distribution at '/opt/OS_Images/pfSense-CE-2.4.1-RELEASE-amd64.iso'

The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
See virt-install man page for various distro examples.
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 15:34:16 virt-install 15804] DEBUG (cli:328) Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start Firewall
otherwise, please restart your installation.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start Firewall
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

Comment: Your `os-type` should not be Linux. pfSense is (currently) `freebsd11.2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an answer per se, but I still can't comment because I do not have 50 rep points. But, I got on and tested that exact same pfsense image with both `cdrom` and `location`. cdrom with vnc seems like the way to go here, since for whatever reason location was having trouble locating a .img file when crawling the iso (I had trouble locating a .img when mounting and searching the .iso myself).

I tried launching it with a cdrom/vnc combo and even specified the port number, etc. but was unable to get anything to happen in my vncviewer (sanity checks against other kvm servers were working though).

I found a github post that used FreeBSD to install pfsense, but I do not know enough about either pfsense or FreeBSD to know if that is the correct way to go (I had and emergency so I could not test it myself). The link for that install is:

https://gist.github.com/mahammad/12624500899a54f721a9

So something like:

```
virt-install --debug --name=Firewall --memory=4096 --vcpus=2 --
cdrom=/opt/OS_Images/pfSense-CE-2.4.1-RELEASE-amd64.iso --
disk=/var/lib/libvirt/images/Firewall.qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio,size=10 -
-network bridge:virbr0   --network bridge:virbr10 --os-type=linux --vnc
```

Then `virsh edit VM_NAME` and search `vnc`. You should see something like:

`<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>`

At this point you should be able to ssh tunnel to localhost:5900 (or whatever port you set vnc to).

Comment: Awesome. This worked.

Answer (score 2):

The `virt-install` option `--location` is used to specify the location of a Linux distribution tree, not a bootable disk image. While it certainly accepts a path to an ISO image, that image must have a Linux distribution on it in order for that to work.

Perhaps you meant to use `--cdrom` instead?

Comment: yes , but that leaves me without a console as per

[Thu, 09 Nov 2017 05:48:27 virt-install 28214] ERROR (cli:315) --extra-args only work if specified with --location. See the man page for examples of using --location with CDROM media

Comment: `virt-install` doesn't understand passing extra args to FreeBSD's bootloader anyway, so you couldn't do that even if you were using `--location`. Like `--location`, `--extra-args` only works with Linux guests. You'll need to find a different way to automate that part of your installation, if desired. As for your console, you specifically asked not to have one with `--nographics`. You should consider dropping that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a raw disk file as virtual disk instead qcow2. And install pfsense from iso.
I solve the same problem in proxmox by using the raw file format

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: Provide a reason for using a raw filesystem . Provide a solution using proxmox. I have never touched proxmox and knowing why and how instead of do this , woukd be better.

Comment: Yes is answer. Proxmox is based on kvm-qemu try to use a raw file. After installation update the conf file in pfsense for load virtio ecc ecc